# Does my Philodendron have warts?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, pest-control, diseases, plant-recommendations

My Philodendron has little black spots that look like warts on the stock/stem. What could it be?

Comment: Is your plant indoor or outdoor - no way of knowing, don't know your location.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Gloria these are the beginnings of a root.When these touch soil or something they can grab a hold of, it enables it to trail along.If you put these in water to root you'll see what I mean.Good way to propagate these.